# Shared Library with JNI: how to maintain global variables?

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, shared-memory

I have written a shared library which is accessed via my linux-system and via a JNI-call from java.

That library should have a global ringbuffer which must be available in the JNI-method and in the other native methods.

I thought this won't be a problem, because when I access the SL from different programs, the global variables are always as they should.

But now, in my JNI-method, the global variables seem to be not initialized (they should as the program-flow forces it).

Here is my example:

```
ringbuf_t ringbuffer;

void internalMethod() {
    // this method is first called from system-program
    ringbuffer = ringbuf_new(5000);
}


JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_example_read(JNIEnv *env, jobject This) {
    // this method is later called via JNI
    if (!ringbuffer) {
        LOGI("uhhh, why is that buffer not set?!");
    }
}
```

What do I have to do to make the ringbuffer-variable really global so every instance/call to the shared-library access one and the same instance of that variable?

Comment: are you sure `internalMethod()` is being called?

Comment: I will re-check it quickly with logging. Seems like you are also wondering. Ah, I think the calls happen in different processes, is that the problem?

Comment: > are you sure internalMethod() is being called? ... yes, I am absolutely sure now. Also the __attribute__((constructor))-method of the SL is called twice, once from System.loadLibrary and once via the system-internal programs.

Comment: different processes have different memory, that's part of the definition of a process

Comment: Hm, it's my first SL and due to my monitorings I thought (and wondered!!) the global variables of a SL are really global. So I have now programed it with that thought. Is there any solution for this problem?

Comment: you probably want to allocate your buffer in shared memory

Comment: Okay there seems to be a way :) I haven't used shared memory explicitly before, have to study that :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments it seems you want to allocate your memory in a process and use it in another.

For this purpose it might be a good idea to look at shared memory: 'man shmget' should be a good start.

Note that this is not specifically related to JNI and is a restriction from the OS.

EDIT:
I would suggest you:

1. read up on shared memory - you should understand the concepts of how this works.
2. first try sharing memory between 2 simple applications
3. only then implement in your JNI application

Comment: Yes that's correct. I allocate a ringbuffer in process #1 if not already allocated and write to it in process #1. And then I would like to grab the data from it in process #2 (JNI). That will be veeeryy funny to understand and change it :)

Comment: As you can see in the example, I'm using a ringbuffer-struct. The buffer itself is created via malloc() in the ringbuf_new()-method. Do I have to also replace this malloc with the shm-methods, or should it be enough to store the `ringbuffer` into a shared-memory?

Comment: As I am under Android, I have sadly no SHMEM available (but ASHMEM). You pushed me into the right direction, thank you!

Comment: you can write into shared memory directly (as if writing to a file). If you intend to be writing and reading into this buffer at the same time you should also do some research on the producer-consumer problem.